# Get Group list with Member data where User is not member or owner of group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Two Collection like following, I'm confused with the query can any one please help to solve,

Group:

```
var WorkKrewSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    content_detail: {
        name: String,
        description: String
    },
    business_info: {
        name: String,
        address: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zipcode: String,
        website: String,
        starting_hours: Date,
        ending_hours: Date,
        days: Array
    },
    created_by: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    created_on: Date,
    updated_on: Date
});
```

Members:

```
var KrewPartnerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Work_krew_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId 
    },
    members: [
        {
            refrence_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            is_sub_admin: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            status: {
                type: String,
                enum: ['accepted', 'declined', 'pending']
            },
            date_of_join: Date
        }
    ]
});
```

**get Groups where:**

- User is not owner of that group as well as not member,
- If user is member then status should be Pending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection `Groups` that contains documents of the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598311f3c63f57ec3dcac86f"),
    "grp_name" : "groupA",
    "created_by" : "userA"
}
```

...and a collection `Members` that contains documents of the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59831310c63f57ec3dcac891"),
    "grp_id" : ObjectId("598311f3c63f57ec3dcac86f"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : "UserY",
            "status" : "pending"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "UserA",
            "status" : "pending"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "UserB",
            "status" : "approved"
        }
    ]
}
```

...you can run the following query for a user called `"UserA"` which should do what you need:

```
db.getCollection('Members').aggregate(
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: "Groups",
      localField: "grp_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "group"
    }
  },
  {
    $match:
    {
      $or:
      [
        {
          "members.user_id": { $ne: "UserA" },
          "group.0.created_by": { $ne: "UserA" }
        },
        {
          "members":
          {
            $elemMatch:
            {
              "user_id": "UserA",
              "status": "pending"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

I would suggest, though, that you merge those two collections into one. A group document should simply contain all its members in which case you wouldn't need the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stuff and could get away with simple queries (without the aggregation framework).

Comment: i have written same condition, but issue is with $in with multiple fields, the $or condition not filtering according to that condition.

Comment: Can you give us an example data set, please, where this would be the case?

Comment: I have updated my question with actual Schema @dnickless